# Posting data using Guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

I am trying to post data using Guzzle 6,

The request which I am generating dynamically looks as below:

```
$postRequest = Array(
    'headers' => array(
        ['x-api-key'] => 'srDxd39M2FQxxvfvxxcIohcLfKDcdcRUU'
    )
    'form_params' => array(
            [0] => Array ( 
                ['name'] => 'function_key' 
                ['contents'] => 'REGISTER' 
            ) 
            [1] => Array ( 
                ['name'] => 'email' 
                ['contents'] => 'tester@test.com' 
            ) 
            [2] => Array ( 
                ['name'] => 'password' 
                ['contents'] => 'test' 
            ) 
            [3] => Array ( 
                ['name'] => 'name' 
                ['contents'] => 'tester' 
            ) 
            [4] => Array ( 
                ['name'] => 'is_org' 
                ['contents'] => 'N' 
            ) 
        )
)
// Sending Request using 'POST' Method                        
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('POST','abcdxyz.com',$getRequest);
```

Now my problem is, The Response which I am receiving after sending the above request says "API 'function_key' is missing".
But I am sending 'function_key' as part of request, then What I am missing here ?? Why it is not able to find 'function_key'

Any help is Appreciated

TIA

Comment: Is your x-api-key and function_key are same ?

Comment: No both are different

Answer (score 0):

Try formating it as follows:

```
$postRequest = [
    'headers' => [
        'x-api-key' => 'srDxd39M2FQxxvfvxxcIohcLfKDcdcRUU'
    ],
    'form_params' => [
        'function_key' => 'REGISTER',
        'email' => 'tester@test.com', 
        'password' => 'test', 
        'name' => 'tester', 
        'is_org' => 'N' 
     ]   
]
```

Comment: His array is the output of print_r but it isn't formatted like in my example.

Comment: @DraskoR I tried formatting like your example, but still same issue

Comment: @VishalVarshney You are also creating a $postRequest variable, but are passing $getRequest on line $response = $client->request('POST','abcdxyz.com',$getRequest);  I guess you misstyped it in your answer but just wanted to comment in case that you left it like that in your code also. Without knowing which API you are using and what format is expected I don't think I can help much more than guessing.